# Display items that are no more than 6 months old

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

What is the correct method to display items that are no more than 6 months (180 days) old? I'm using the following code, but it seems to be showing items that don't fit the criterion accurately.

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(e.DateCreated)).Days <= 180
```

Where could I have gone wrong?

**Edit**

Thanks everyone for your help. Turns out the hours were a key factor in deciding the age of an item. I don't really need it to be accurate to the hour, just to the date.

Comment: Where is the LINQ part?

Comment: Oops, my bad. No LINQ, I've edited the question.

Comment: Six months in the western calendar is closer to 183 days (not sure if it is relevant).

Comment: What is the type of `e.DateCreated`? String?

Comment: `e.DateCreated` is a DateTime field

Comment: Then I can't see why it would not work. The `Convert.ToDateTime` part is not needed if the compile-time type (declared type) of `DateCreated` is already `DateTime`, but it would work with that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use this to get a date six months ago

```
var sixMonthsAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-180);
```

and then compare it with whatever you want to compare. I guess

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(e.DateCreated) >= sixMonthsAgo)
```

in your case.

**EDIT:**

I performed a test with a test value provided in comments.

```
var input = DateTime.Parse("2013-06-23 18:14:47.937");
```

My current date is **21.12.2013** and time is about **11:00 AM**.

With that defined, your code yields a result

> 180.16:39...

So it still meets your requirements, since it is exactly 180 days old + few hours and minutes.

My code yields a result

> 24.6.2013 about 11:00 AM

and since your date is **23.6.** then it is older then the result and therefore does not meet your requirements.

As you can see, the hours play a big role here. So in the end, it very much depends on how you define "180 days ago". If you still feel that neither of the variants work well, give me at least 10 days you compare, both where it works and where it does not work and mark which should be older and which not.

Comment: Thanks for that. Tried it out, but still having the same issue.

Comment: All right, I need the following info to find the problem: your current CultureInfo and value of e.DateCreated

Comment: Used `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`to display CultureInfo but turns out blank. A sample value of `e.DataCreated` is `2013-06-23 18:14:47.937`.

Comment: And what is the expected output for this date? Should it be older than 180 days?

Comment: I have a list and I only want to display items that are 180 days old or less.

Comment: I get it, but tell me, if this date `2013-06-23 18:14:47.937` should be older than 180 days in your situation? It shows me that it should be based on http://www.convertunits.com/dates/from/Jun+23,+2013/to/Dec+21,+2013

Comment: I created an item that's older than 180 days on purpose so that it won't be displayed. Just to confirm that the code works.

Comment: Thanks Ondrej. I think having it correct up to the date is sufficient. Really appreciate you taking the time to look into this. Cheers!

Comment: @nouptime I'm glad that you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(e.datecreated);

if (ts.TotalDays <= 180)
{
 //perform some task
}
```

Comment: Please explain why it is better than the original code in the question.